# Linebreak missing in WebStorm's markdown editor

Tags: markdown, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I write markdown in WebStorm, there is a problem with missing linebreaks. This occurs for example with the reply quotation example on Jetbrains' help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/markdown-syntax.html#ReplyQuotation

[image]

If I copy and paste it into WebStorm, the linebreak between the first two entries is missing:

[image]

Is this a bug, am I typing something wrong, or can I change the behavior somewhere?

In the comments I was pointed to another question where linebreaks in Markdown are discussed. This explains in part the behavior (and shows that the example from Jetbrain's documentation may be wrong).

But even considering Markdown's linebreak behavior, I do not understand why the following example is rendered in two lines:

[image]

Meanwhile I came to the conclusion that not using reply quotes in my Markdown will make my life less stressful.

Edit: I am using WebStorm 2020.2 Build #WS-202.6397.88

Comment: In fact, the second behaviour is (probably) correct (assuming there's no trailing whitespace).

Comment: "Meanwhile I came to the conclusion that not using reply quotes in my Markdown will make my life less stressful"—so will using _line breaks_. Blank lines separating things are almost always a good idea in Markdown (and they make the source easier to read too, which was a design goal of the language). Inside a block quote, some implementations will still require a `>`, but lines with just that on them before and after the nested blockquote should help.

Comment: @Chris Right, but WebStorm has this weird behavior to add an extra angled bracket when pressing return in a reply quotation. It feels very weird and unintuitive, so since I found a good solution without reply quotations, I decided that not using them will make my life easier.